# Swift Extension Conditional on Version

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift package that includes an extension of a SwiftUI View.

E.g.

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {}
```

As SwiftUI was introduced in iOS 13 this will not compile for any OS version that targets less than iOS 13. I am looking to add a condition to this extension so that it is only included if it meets the minimum SwiftUI system requirements.

I have tried adding `@availiable` but that is unavailable for extensions. I have also tried adding `#if canImport(SwiftUI)` but there appears to be situations where SwiftUI can be imported but View does not exist.

Is a solution to this possible?

Comment: Can you post what `@available` property you tried? You may just not have included enough information to limit availability when compiled on macOS. Give `@available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)` a try.